# How can I iterate over shell function completions and alias completions before external command completions in zsh?

Tags: command-line, zsh, auto-completion

As it stands when I hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> to iterate over possible completions for a partial command external command completions are iterated first:

```
user@user-X550CL ~ % apt
Completing external command
apt                       aptd                      apt-key                 
apt-add-repository        aptdcon                   apt-mark                
apt-cache                 apt-extracttemplates      apt-sortpkgs            
apt-cdrom                 apt-ftparchive            apturl                  
apt-config                apt-get                   apturl-gtk              
Completing shell function
apt-get_all
Completing alias
apt-get_autoremove_clean  apt-get_update            apt-get_update_upgrade
```

In the above example it'd took 17 more hit on <kbd>TAB</kbd> to get to `apt-get_autoremove_clean` (or to type an additional `-get_` and to hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> 3 more times).

In most cases I'd find it way more convenient if shell functions and aliases would be iterated first.

Is there a way to setup `zsh` to iterate over shell functions and aliases first?

Comment: Reference: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Completion-System-Configuration

Comment: Is there some reason you cannot run `bash`?  `bash` does this inherently.

Comment: @Daniel it does? That's news to me. For me, bash doesn't even distinguish between functions, commands or aliases in completion. `sudo<tab>` gets me `sudo        sudoa       sudoedit    sudof       sudoreplay` in one line.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean.  See answer below

Comment: @Rinzwind Yes, RTFM, you're right. However that documentation is *vast*, and I know very little about `zsh`; Googling that didn't avail as well. I thought someone might have had it right in the hat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the docs, this might do the trick:

```
$ zstyle ':completion:*:*:-command-:*' group-order aliases functions commands
$ sudo<tab>
sudoa
sudof
sudo        sudoedit    sudoreplay
```

(In case it's not obvious, `sudoa` is an alias and `sudof` is a function.)

Comment: Flawless, thanks. However in my installation aliases / shell functions / external commands are nicely separated as in the example in my question, maybe that depends on your configuration?

Comment: @kos I suppose so. I have no idea how you even did that. I didn't even know about grouping until I saw `group-name` in the doc.

Comment: FWIW if you want to debug this it always did that since I started using it (by default, I chose to auto-configure `~/.zshrc` at the first run). zsh 5.0.7 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: @kos nah. I have relatively few aliases and functions. Not worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

Another answerer gave the command to run, but didn't tell you how to make it default.

Run this command:

```
echo "zstyle ':completion:*:*:-command-:*' group-order aliases functions commands" >> ~/.zshrc
```